# C++ loops continually evaluating if statement, making it too slow

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, loops, for-loop

I currently have a C++ program which is supposed to generate every possible domain name up to a set number of digits. The code I have is current pretty verbose (this is fine) but also tediously slow once it starts generating past 4 digits. The loops where things really start to go wrong are shown here:

```
const char* chars[] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k",
"l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z", "0", "1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "-"};
int char_num = 1;

[...]

if(char_num == 5) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < 37; j++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < 37; k++) {
          for(int l = 0; l < 37; l++) {
            for(int m = 0; m < 36; m++) {
              cout << "adding " << chars[i] << chars[j] << chars[k] << chars[l] << chars[m] << ".com to list\n";
              if(i == 35 && j == 36 && k == 36 && l == 36 && m == 35) {
                char_num++;
                cout << "Generating to " << char_num + 1  << " characters\n";
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am intending at least three or four additional if statements after this one, with incrementally more for loops in each. I'm also going to need to write the output to a file, and to use this file to do DNS lookups, so I need every drop of performance I can get so I'm not waiting weeks for the program to complete.

My main concern at present is that the program is evaluating the if statement on every single interation which I presume is having a significant effect on performance, given the number of nested loops. To stop this I tried moving the if statement into a separate function and having it return a value once it finished, but I noticed that when I do this I'm not able to log to the console from within the function, which makes things more complicated.

What is the correct process for doing this in C++ and are there any other ways to speed up the code? I did try  writing the code in node.js before but it went berserk and threw a bunch of out of memory errors when I started writing to a file, and I figured C++ would probably be quicker anyway, hence I switched languages.

Comment: Might want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914946/all-permutations-of-length-k-from-n-characters-with-repetition-in-cpp

Comment: Comment your `cout << "adding " ...` and you will see that the displaying takes all the execution time. So I think the main concern is how you can dump your data efficiently in a file or rather several files. By the way, your if condition can be removed.

Comment: The condition will short circuit, so `if(i == 35)` will be the entire test, unless `i` actually *is* 35. Comparing an `int` value to a constant, and with a consistent result, is as close to zero cost you will get. We are talking nanoseconds on a modern x86.

Comment: 65646288 iterations need to be done to complete the process, for CPUs is nearly nothing if you done in singe loop just math or logic operations. But as previous comment's says you are printing on screen and this operation is really time consuming.

Comment: Removing the cout and replacing with file io has improved speed by perhaps 50x (rough estimate) and switching out the if statement probably about doubled the speed. For 7 characters the code now completes within about 20 seconds. Thanks everyone for the help so far. Hopefully with all the suggestions here I can optimise to make 12+ characters feasible on the hardware I have available... then I have to think about optimising the DNS lookups...

Comment: You should think about optimizing by abandoning your project. Why on earth would you want to run DOS attack on DNS? There are ways to obtain list of registered domains other than this brute force attack. This way you are still missing lot of cool domains like stackoverflow, which is 13 chars long :-) And I am not mentioning this one www.thelongestdomainnameintheworldandthensomeandthensomemoreandmore.com

Comment: @MarekVitek This isn't intended to be a brute force attack, though I could understand why you'd think it would be. Rather I want as complete a list of registered domain names as possible. If I can I would like to minimise stress on both my own computers and any DNS servers I query, as what I'm interested in here is usable data.

Comment: I understand, that you don't mean to do it intentionally but you will. Running it from one computer will not make it too harsh. You can just download the list from services, that provide them. Just googled this https://wwws.io/ It looks it is not free, but you will get more data than by your scanning.

Comment: @MarekVitek the reason I chose to do it this way is because it looked from a cursory inspection as if only members of certain governmental and academic organisations had access (despite there being no law against members of the public holding this info) which seemed elitist. I also tried the official RIPE-NCC database query program, but that failed to install with a maven error. However, I'll look into this company and see, as it now looks like a direct download will be possible after all. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You don't have to stick with this one. It was just example and first thing I was able to find with google. I have also noticed that you may be able to obtain zone files from domain registrars. Just give google a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement seems to be checking for the end of the loop. There is a simple solution to avoid this: remove the `if` and put the code *after* the loop!

However, if you need to add more `if`s that depend on loop variables, I don't really know how you can optimize it. *Don't*, however, put them in a function: the overhead of calling the function will slow your code (and an optimizing compiler will inline your function anyway).

Here are a few possibilities you can explore:

- use multithreading/multiprocessing. If done well, this can divide the execution time by up to the number of CPU cores on your computer
- enable compiler optimization (`-O3` or `-Ofast` with `g++`)

---

One last thing: if the consumer program accepts data from the standard input, piping the output of your program into it will be twice as fast as generating the names *then* using them. EG instead of

```
producer > storage.txt
consumer < storage.txt
```

do

```
producer | consumer
```

Comment: Thanks. These are useful suggestions. I'll try implementing them and see if they help significantly.

Comment: Before optimizing anything, I would recommend to understand first why your code takes time. Then you can think about multithreading.

Answer (score 2):

Focus on code optimizations. In the statement you are constantly re accessing the same member of the char array every iteration wasting clock cycles.

```
`cout << "adding " << chars[i] << chars[j] << chars[k] << chars[l] << chars[m] << ".com to list\n";`
```

A way to optimize this is by adding temporary variables.

```
char tempI;
char tempJ;
char tempK;
char tempL;
if(char_num == 5) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    tempI = char[i];
      for(int j = 0; j < 37; j++) {
        tempJ = char[j];
          for(int k = 0; k < 37; k++) {
           tempK = char[k];
            for(int l = 0; l < 37; l++) {
             tempL = char[l];
              for(int m = 0; m < 36; m++) {
                cout << "adding " << tempI << tempJ << tempK << tempL << 
  chars[m] << ".com to list\n";
                if(i == 35 && j == 36 && k == 36 && l == 36 && m == 35) {
                char_num++;
                cout << "Generating to " << char_num + 1  << " characters\n";
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

There are things you can do that make your code faster in regards to temporal and spatial locality just by the way you write it.

Also use compiler optimizations -03 with g++, etc.

Or consider rewriting your algorithm, because there might be a better way altogether in regards to time complexity